# reason for wrapping an anchor in a form?

Tags: html

This is one of those "found in someone else's code and wondering what they're thinking" questions...

The HTML being generated is of the form

```
<form method="post" action="#">
  <a href="?some&query&string&stuff">
    <img src="https://www.example.com/pictures/pict.gif" /></a>
</form>
```

The form has no other contents than the anchor and the image inside of it. Is there some reason to wrap an anchor in a form like that?

The only reason I can guess is to make it selectable in CSS, but it would seem the obvious solution for that is a `<div class="my_anchor_wrapper">`.

So I'm wondering if there's something magic about this construct that I'm missing.

Thanks for any HTMLightenment here.

Comment: Probably just bad coding :o)

Comment: I wonder if there is some JavaScript elsewhere on the page that finds this element and makes some magic happen.

Comment: This looks like a  [Duplicate to this Quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395269/what-do-form-action-and-form-method-post-action-do), the answers there may be helpful.

Comment: The coder doesn't want Google indexes his queried URLs and hides query in the form.

Comment: @Evgeniy, are you saying that putting a link inside a form element makes Google treat it like it had `rel="nofollow"` set? I've never heard of that but if it is the case it might make sense here.

Comment: Never heard about this kind of handling (form link as nofollow) - it is too nice to be true:) It seems that i firstly misunderstood the code: i thought it would be like `<form method="post" action="?some&query&string&stuff">`. But nevertheless, the coder seems to think, a link placed in the form would be less accessible for the Googlebot.